# Can't use vector of unique_ptr in Emscripten bindings

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, smart-pointers, emscripten

I am trying to bind some variables with [Emscripten Bindings](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html). And the problem is when I want to bind a vector of unique_ptr, emscripten try copy each entry and this obviously cause a compile error.

`error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::__1::unique_ptr ...`

`note: copy constructor is implicitly deleted because 'unique_ptr<...>'  has a user-declared move constructor`

But in the documentation of emscripten, they says that support unique_ptr.

Code:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    using Entities = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Entity>>;
public:
    auto entities() const -> Entities const & { return _entities; }
private:
    Entities _entities;
};

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(MyClass) {
    emscripten::class_<MyClass>("MyClass")
        .property("entities", &MyClass::entities);
}
```

I can duplicate the vector with simple pointers but it's not a real solution. There is a special option/policy in emscripten to handle unique_ptr ?

#### EDIT

It looks like emscripten doesn't support unique_ptr in a vector. So to avoid duplication of data, a function to get directly one entry on the vector that return the pointer could be a good solution.

Comment: If you could think of simple pointers, why not use shared_ptr instead of unique_ptr ?

Comment: Of course it's works with shared_ptr but in this case, there is no point to use shared_ptr without emscripten.

Comment: Even if Emscripten could support it, what would it even mean? Would Javascript be able to access its own copy of the vector (in which you need to find a way to copy all the `unique_ptr`s) or does it access the original vector, perhaps via a pointer to the vector? If the latter is acceptable, could you do `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Entity>>>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation

> embind has built-in support for return values of type std::unique_ptr.

The way I interperate this is it has built in support for functions that have a return type of `std::unique_ptr`.  It does not mention about having support for containers that have non copyable memebers

Answer (score 0):

The class `unique_ptr` can only be *moved* and not *copied.* It seems that whatever the BINDINGS macro is doing is internally making copies of the objects within the vector. Since copying requires having a copy constructor and `unique_ptr`'s copy destructor has been `delete`d, you're getting that compiler error. The workaround could be to possibly copy the `Entity` and construct a separate `unique_ptr` to it.